# Is it possible to add textBlock to windows phone 7 Applicationbar

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

In my ebook app, I wanted to show current page number as as textBlock on Application bar.

I couldn't find a way to add textBlock to the application bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check this: [Bindable Application Bar Extensions for Windows Phone 7](http://www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/10/bindable-application-bar-extensions-for-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: Looks really promising by looks of it...Thanks a ton for answering

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot modify the application bar itself. To build something like you'd need to create your own application bar style control.

I'm not entirely sure if this is a good thing because it would be inconsistent with the rest of the phone and could possibly violate some style guides.

Comment: yaa...I suspected that... Thanks a lot for confirming :-)